# How do I compare multiple columns with a list of values in a table using sql in the most efficient way

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got multiple columns 'CD','CD2','CD3','CD4','CD5','CD6','CD7'..... up to 20 in a Table called Table1, that contain a value, however some are null.

I want to compare each columns value from Table Table1 against all values of column "Code" from Table Ref. I also want to return column "name" from the Table Ref where it matches.

Lets say:

TABLE: Table1

```
CD          CD2          CD3
Value1      Value2       Value9
Value2      Value3       Value10
Value3      Value4       Value11
```

TABLE: Ref

```
Code                 Name
Value1               Blah
Peach                moo
April                cow
Value2               dog
Value11              can
....
```

The code I've written is something along the line as below, but its taking AGES!!! ARGH. Is there a better way to do this??

```
select a.*,b.name
from Table1 a,ref b where 
(a.CD = b.CODE or CD2 = b.CODE or CD3 = b.CODE or CD4 = b.CODE or CD5 = b.CODE or CD6 = b.CODE or
CD7 = b.CODE or CD8 = b.CODE or CD9 = b.CODE or CD10 = b.CODE or CD11 = b.CODE or CD12 = b.CODE or
CD13 = b.CODE or CD14 = b.CODE or CD15 = b.CODE or CD16 = b.CODE or CD17 = b.CODE or CD18 = b.CODE or
CD19 = b.CODE or CD20 = b.CODE;
```

Comment: `where b.code in (a.cd, a.cd1, a.cd2, a.cd3 ...)` - but I doubt it will be faster. It is the same thing, just written differently. Unrelated but: you should really stop using those outdated implicit joins in the where clause and start using an explicit `JOIN` operator

Comment: I tried where a.cd in (select code from ref) or a.cd2 in (select code from ref)...  While seems a Lot quicker,  but I don't get back the name from ref.  Which I'm happy with if it improves the performance,  is there any better..  Faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is more efficient to do separate joins on each column:

```
select t.*, r1.name, r2.name, . . .
from table1 t left join
     ref r1
     on r1.code = a.cd left join
     ref r2
     on r2.code = a.cd2 left join
     . . .
```

This should have better performance and it puts the values on the same row.

As a note:  you have a poor data structure.  You should normalize your data so you have one row per `table1` entity and code.

EDIT:

You can check that at least one code matches by using:

```
where r1.code is not null or r2.code is not null or . . .
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but tried the query and it seems to return back rows that do not match the values in Ref table.